# Consuming RESTful API in Java, generating artifacts.

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am tasked with creating a layer in Java/Spring that consumes web services from a couple different providers. These services define specific request beans but the end points do not publish XSD information.

What would be the best way to generate the artifacts required to consume these services? It seems building our own request objects is not the best way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST services do not offer XSD as the WSDL of a traditional SOAP service. Some REST frameworks offer WADL, or the may user Swagger.io to describe the service, or expose documentation like Spring boots actuator /docs.

If there is no such documentation, and you can't get the source code for the system you are integrating with, I recommend that you build your own set of Java POJOs so you can interface with the service in a typed manner. 
I have done that for multiple systems that expose (online) documented REST services, but do not provide a set of DTO that you can use when consuming them.

Comment: Thanks. This is the route I have decided to go. Although not published, I have been given internal XSD files for each service and am using the jaxb2-maven-plugin to build these artifacts.

Comment: If you have XSD, you should use the code generation tool (jaxb2-maven-plugin) to create the classes. Be aware that the code generation may leave @WebServiceClient annotation inside you code, this will have an effect if you deploy on a JavaEE server..

Comment: Thank you. The issue I now have are name conflicts within some of the XSD files, causing the generation to fail. I have found that I can configure multiple schemas, but with so many XSD files, this seems unreasonable. Is there a way for each XSDs generated classes to be namespaced beyond the <packageName> argument?

Comment: I don't use maven (I use Gralde), so previously I have just generated the code by running the command-line utility directly. This works as long as the XSD doesn't change often.